# Ubuntu 16.04: VLC is not removing

Tags: 16.04, dependencies, vlc, software-uninstall

I am try to remove VLC from my Ubuntu 16.04 version but I'm getting this error:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:  libvlccore8 :
Depends: vlc-data (= 2.2.2-5ubuntu0.16.04.4) but 4.0.0~rc1~~git20180102+r73456+113~ubuntu16.04.1 is to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Then I tried `apt-get -f install` as mention in above error, but that outputs the following error:

```
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu9) ...
Errors were encountered while processing: /var/cache/apt/archives/libvlccore8_3.0.0~~git20171210+r73147+99~ubuntu16.04.1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Please help to get this done.

Comment: Remove the VLC PPA you added and try again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `apt-get remove --purge libvlccore8 vlc-data` and all packages related to VLC